# Can you allocate space at the bottom of a .NET Chart Control

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I'm using the .net chart control. I'd like to allocate some space at the bottom of the chart to add some additional information (date, associated file name, note, etc.) - about 0 to 4 lines in total. To do this I'd like to allocate some reserved space below the X axis title (the 0 to 4 lines worth) and use an annotation anchored to the bottom to contain the additional information. Or, if there's some other way to accomplish the same thing, that would be great.

I've been working for a couple of days trying to accomplish this but have not found a "professional" way to do it. I am able to do it by adding several blank lines to the X axis label, but I'd like something a little better than that.

I am using a dock style of fill and allowing auto sizing. I've tried margins and padding with no success. Annotations appear to simply overlay existing area on the chart but do not allocate any additional space.

I'm looking to allocate a fixed size block at the bottom since the text block will be a fixed size height, rather than a percentage (relative coordinates).

Does anyone have any suggestions that I might try? Thanks!

Comment: Well, don't use Dock = Fill.  Gets you lots of space around the graph so you can add whatever you need.  A bit of pragmatism is appropriate here.

Comment: I use dock=fill on the chart object so that it fills it's container (a form). I'm looking for the added space between the bottom of the X axis title and the bottom of the chart - I want the annotation to essentially be part of the chart. I'm assuming that even with dock != fill, the chart area, axes, titles, etc. would still fill the chart object similarly to how they do now.

Comment: By the way Hans, I'm new to the forum and just learning how to use it. I got caught up in explaining what I'm trying to do and forgot to say thanks for your comment and for taking the time to reply. I will give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish what I was looking to do. I simply used a chart Title and docked it to the bottom of the chart. It allows me to add in the extra data that I wanted to add and space is properly allocated for it. I'm new to using MSCharts and hadn't noticed that I could use multiple titles docked to different places on the chart.